# How to add string and datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

i have a string like this (YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM):

```
0000/01/00/00/00/00
```

I need to add this string and now's data. I give now's data via

```
datetime.now()
```

I try to use:

```
conv_data = datetime.strptime('0000/01/00/00/00/00', '%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S')
conv_data + datetime.now()
```

but it doesn't work because Year, Month and etc. must be greater then zero. Can you help me to solve my problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to just add a month to the current datetime?

In that case you could do this:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

Output: `datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 11, 11, 52, 34, 952997)`

Edit for YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM format:

```
date_res2 = datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=+1)
date_res2.strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M')
```

Output: '2021/02/12/09/33'

Comment: Good idea, but, unfortunately, I must work only with YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM format

Comment: In that case you can just store the output in a new variable and then specify the format:  see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing so would be using split()

Ex.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = '0000/01/00/00/00/00'
date_array = date_string.split('/')

conv_data = datetime.strptime('-'.join(date_array [0:3])+" " + ':'.join(date_array [3:]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using

```
date = '0000/01/00/00/00/00'
now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S')
date_res = []
for now, date in zip(now.split('/'), date.split('/')):
    date_res.append(str(int(now)+ int(date)))
print('/'.join(date_res))
```